# Passing python list to Microsoft SQL query as parameters twice in one query

Tags: python

I have a script that is intended take in items as user input, put those items into an Microsoft SQL query, and to run that query. It will then put it into an excel sheet using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


cnxn = create_engine(mssql+pyodbc://<connection_string>?driver=SQL+Server)
end_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
start_date = (date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

temp_list = ('item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
    'item4')
placeholder = = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(temp_list)))

query = f"""
    SELECT something
    FROM Table
    where date between {start_date} and {end_date}
        and name IN ({placeholder})
    UNION(
    SELECT something
    FROM other_table
    where date between {start_date} and {end_date}
        and name IN ({placeholder}))
df = pd.read_sql_query(SERVICE_GROUPS, cnxn, params=sg_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('foo.xlsx', datetime_format='hh:mm:ss')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar', index=False)
writer.save()
```

This returns a traceback saying

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 8 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

[SQL: 
    SELECT something
    FROM Table
    where date between 2022-03-04 and 2022-06-02
        and name IN (?, ?, ?, ?)

    UNION
    (SELECT something
    FROM Table
    where date between 2022-03-04 and 2022-06-02
        and name IN (?, ?, ?, ?))]
                             
[parameters: ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4')]
```

Obviously there are 8 "?" markers for the items(4) in the list, this is because the query uses the list twice. How can I make this work with the same list being used twice in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Well after posting this I noticed that I could just add the list to itself and it got me where I needed to go

```
temp_list = ('item1',
'item2',
'item3',
'item4')
temp_list = temp_list + temp_list
```